# Быстрый доступ к закрытому массиву

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, ооп

Есть некоторый класс, содержащий массив с координатами в виде закрытого поля, и абстрактный класс для создания расширений:

```
public class Simulator
{
    private Vector3[] _pos;

    public abstract class Extension
    {
        protected Simulator Simulator { get; set; }

        protected Extension(Simulator simulator)
        {
            Simulator = simulator;
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Как получить *быстрый* и *безопасный* доступ к элементам массива `_pos` (с возможностью изменений) из расширений?

Как я понял из [статьи](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1819-properties-should-not-return-arrays) возврат массива не является корректным выходом в данной ситуации.

Comment: "быстрый и безопасный" - а понять, что это значит, мы должны, заглянув к Вам в мозг?

Comment: Вопрос в том, чего именно вы хотите добиться. Не существует «правильного метода давать доступ к данным». Скажите, какие операции должны делать расширения, и мы скажем, какая структура данных вам нужна.

Comment: Класс `Simulator` содержит координаты (`_pos`), скорости и ускорения частиц. С помощью расширений я хочу добавлять в симулятор дополнительные компоненты типа термостата, баростата и тд. Для их работы необходим доступ к координатам, скоростям и ускорениям, желательно максимально быстрый, так как важна скорость работы. По задумке на каждом шаге моделирования `Simulator` будет вызывать некоторый метод у расширений, который и будет обеспечивать функциональность этих расширений.

Comment: @VladD Доступ к `_pos` для чтения и записи

Comment: @asyncawait: Вот прямо они должны суметь присвоить в `_pos` другой массив?

Comment: @VladD расширения должны суметь изменить при необходимости значения определенных элементов `_pos`, а также, скорее всего, добавлять и удалять определенные элементы

Comment: А что означает «добавлять и удалять»? Например, могут ли они удалить нулевой элемент со сдвигом всех остальных?

Comment: @VladD может потребоваться удалить одну или несколько частиц из симулятора, для этого нужно удалить соответствующие значения координат, скоростей и ускорений. Получается что могут удалить и нулевой элемент. Логичнее было бы использовать List вместо массивов и передавать ссылки на них в расширения. Но при этом нужно ограничить добавление (или удаление) элементов в `_pos`, `_vel`, `_acc` по отдельности. То есть добавление частицы означает добавление элемента в каждый из этих массивов. У частицы не может например быть ускорение, но не быть координат

Comment: @asyncawait: А почему бы не завести класс (или структуру) `Particle`, в которой есть позиция, скорость и ускорение, и передавать в `Extension` просто `List<Particle>`?

Comment: @VladD В процессе работы программы будет постоянно производиться интегрирование уравнений движения, такой подход не скажется на производительности?

Comment: @asyncawait: Ну спрофилируйте. _Преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед_ (ц).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем функцию (или свойство, как вам нравится) в класс-расширение

```
public class Simulator
{
    private Vector3[] _pos;

    public abstract class Extension
    {
        protected Simulator Simulator { get; set; }

        protected Extension(Simulator simulator)
        {
            Simulator = simulator;          
        }  

        protected Vector3[] GetPos()
        {
            return Simulator?._pos;
        }
    }   
}
```

Используем её в наследниках

```
public class Extension1 : Simulator.Extension
{
    public Extension1(Simulator simulator) : base(simulator)
    {

    }

    private void Foo()
    {
        var pos = GetPos();
        pos[0] = new Vector3();
    }
}
```

Если вам надо вернуть копию массива

```
        protected Vector3[] GetPos()
        {
            if (Simulator?._pos == null) return null;

            var copy = new Vector3[Simulator._pos.Length]
            Array.Copy(Simulator._pos,copy, Simulator._pos.Length);
            return copy;
        }
```

Comment: А чем такой подход лучше создания ссылки `protected Vector3[] Pos` в классе `Extension`?

Comment: Лучше для чего?

Comment: Почему нельзя создать поле в классе `Extension` с ссылкой на `Simulator._pos`? Для меня, как для новичка, такой вариант был бы более очевидным, но я так понимаю что такой такой вариант не самый правильный.

Comment: @asyncawait вы задаете неверный вопрос. Сделать можно что угодно в коде, вопрос в том, какой код делает именно то, что вам нужно для решения вашей задачи.